# Example for the Tate's theorem, Group cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Tate's theorem can be found in [Milne's book](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf) page 81. Can someone give an easy example for that?

Comment: I would like to answer your question, but I can't find a theorem of Tate on page 81. Do you mean the theorem of Tate-Nakayama?

Comment: Sorry, this is the link

Comment: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the theorem of Tate-Nakayama. It implies local class field theory with $C = \bar{K}^\times$ (see p. 105) and global class field theory with $C$ the idele class group (see p. 198).